# User object returns None in ManytoMany

Tags: python, django

I have a many to many relationship between the User object and Movement object. Everytime I run the test to see of the User object was successfully added, I get a auth.User.None

Models:

```
class Movement(models.Model):
    zipcode = models.ForeignKey('ZipCode')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=False, 
        blank=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Movement, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Form:

```
class MovementForm(forms.ModelForm):  

    title= forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Movement title")
    description = forms.CharField(help_text="Movement description",
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'paceholder':'Please enter your description'}))
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Movement
        exclude = ['zipcode', 'users']
```

View:

```
@login_required
def new_movement(request):
    template = 'new_movement.html'


    if request.method == 'POST':
        zipcode_form = ZipCodeForm(data=request.POST)
        movement_form = MovementForm(data=request.POST)

        if zipcode_form.is_valid() and movement_form.is_valid():
            zipcode, create = ZipCode.objects.get_or_create(**zipcode_form.cleaned_data)
            movement = movement_form.save(commit=False)
            movement.zipcode = zipcode
            movement.save()
            movement.users.add(request.user)
            movement.save()
            return redirect('/%s/results' %zipcode.zipcode)
    else:

        zipcode_form = ZipCodeForm()
        movement_form = MovementForm()

    return render(request, template, 
        {'movement_form':movement_form, 'zipcode_form':zipcode_form})

    return render(request, template, {} )
```

Everything runs fine, but when I run my test code hoping to get the name of the User, all I get is auth.User.None.

test.py:

```
class NewMovementViewTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='Megan',
            email='megan@email.com',
            password='password',
        )
        self.client.login(username='Megan', password='password')

    def test_new_movement_saves_user(self):

        response = self.client.post('/new_movement/',
            data={'title':'A movement',
            'zipcode':20016,
            'description':'Some movement'})
        movements = Movement.objects.all()
        self.assertEqual(movements.count(), 1)
        movement= movements[0]
        self.assertEqual(movement.title, 'A movement')
        self.assertEqual(movement.zipcode.zipcode, 20016)
        self.assertEqual(movement.description, 'Some movement')
        users = Movement.objects.filter(users__username__startswith="Megan")
        print(users[0].users)
```

Test Output:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
auth.User.None
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.191s

OK
```

Comment: What do you mean by "auth.User.None"? Please show the actual output.

Comment: But you just created a `Movement`, did you associate any users to it?

Comment: I thought I did in the new_movement view, I saved the movement first and then added the User to it.

Comment: What tests have you done? What have you proven already? Get the admin site up and running. It is one of your most useful debugging tools in checking the state of your data. You can visually check if these objects exist and whether or not they are connected in their many-to-many field. If the admin site shows they are connected, your test is broken. If it doesn't show what you want it to, then we can start tearing apart your code to find the problem.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong, I was treating the ManytoMany relationship as a ForeignKey one. Should have been using a reverse lookup with the related_name tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
        users = Movement.objects.filter(users__username__startswith="Megan")
```

Just a note about naming - this is going to return a 'Movement' queryset - not any User information. It *will* return movement objects based on the filter (which in this case is filtering across the relationship); but please be aware they are Movement objects, not User objects.

You can use indexes to get the first Movement object - but `users[0].users` is going to return a object manager (specifically 'ManyRelatedManager'). If you want to inspect the users associated with this object, you can treat it like most other object managers and do something like:

```
user = users[0].users.first()
```

or

```
all_users = users[0].users.all()
```

Feel free to refer to the Django guide - it has some nice examples on many-to-many relationships. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/